# Javascript, zoom in, etc not working in Android Webview (Jetpack Compose : Accompanist Webview library)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I made a webview but when actually using it, neither the javascript, nor the zoom in settings seem to work.

Here is the function

```
fun OpenWebView(state: WebViewState) {
WebView(
    state,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(350.dp),
    onCreated = { webView ->
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
        webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        webView.settings.displayZoomControls = false
        webView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        webView.settings.defaultTextEncodingName = "utf-8"
        webView.settings.pluginState = WebSettings.PluginState.ON
    },
    client = remember {
        object :
            AccompanistWebViewClient() {

        }
    },
    chromeClient = remember {
        object : AccompanistWebChromeClient() {

        }
    }
)
```

}

The webview simply opens the page but nothing of the javascript works.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue.